# How to read the zsh shell variables

Tags: go, zsh

I am running my go program, from `zsh`. The program needs to read `$fpath` variables. But trying to read `fpath` on `Os.Env`, but it is returning empty string(ie. like the variable does not exist).

I am not sure why this should be happening since the variable is already available in the shell. What could be an explanation for this?

Also, any solutions to how can the above be accomplished within the go program?

Comment: Are you using the same case as the shell does? That is, if it’s FPATH in the shell, fpath won’t work in the code, it needs to be used as FPATH there too.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please include a (partial) list of the shells environment.

Comment: It is possible that you spawned the go program from a different shell.

Comment: You cannot read it - because it's not an environment variable.

Comment: Zsh shell variables are private to the shell process. Either put them into the environment, or write them to some file which you then read from your GO program.

Comment: @AdityaKuamrGupta: Perhaps you forgot to put it into the environment? Inside zsh, do a `printenv fpath` to verifiy this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the values of the zsh variables to make it available to an external process such as your Go program via environment variables or command-line arguments.

In the following commands you can replace `/usr/bin/env` by your own program.

```
my_fpath="$fpath" env
my_fpath="$fpath" env | grep my_fpath
```

Answer (score 2):

Go, or any other application for that matter, can't access zsh variables. I think you are confused with environmental variables.
Run `printenv` in your shell and notice it won't list your `fpath` variable either.

If you want this variable to be available to an application, use shell expansion to put it in the environment when executing an application;
`FPATH="$fpath" printenv`

Or pass it as an argument and read it using the `flags`-package;
`./app -fpath "$fpath"`